# The best option to multi-platform 2d mobile development

Tags: android, iphone, cross-platform, mobile

we are in the process of porting a game from iphone(made with cocos2s) to android(using the andEngine), and it has been a pain to do. So for our next project (a 2d game) we are thinking about using some multiplatform engine/framework. For now we are thinking about testing both unity, marmaled(former airplay sdk) and cocos2d-x. Do you have any opinion about this? Does someon have experience developing 2d games using Unity?

Comment: "Best" is subjective.  What are you looking for?  Cost? Ease of use?  Overall speed?  Existing toolset?  I'm sure each of those projects you mentioned has its pluses and minuses.  Unity has been used for a lot of 2D games. http://unity3d.com/gallery/game-list/#ios

Comment: Overall speed, given we will be releasing the game for both android and iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently working on Unity to make a 2d game, not for mobile devices though. What I'm doing to keep it 2d is just to set the Z axis rotation of the camera to 0, and only move it on the X and Y axes. If you can afford the iOS license of Unity, then go for it, Unity really saves time on development, and you can make 3d games easily without messing with openGLES.

Answer (score 0):

People have used cocos2d-x on top of Marmalade to add features such as particles that it is missing.